# Is it possible to have both css and scss in Angular

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-cli

I am including a stand-alone build module which uses .scss (SASS) into an existing Angular app set up with plain CSS. Is it possible to have these both next to each other and does it need any custom configuration for example in the `angular-cli.json` defaults section:

```
"defaults": {
  "styleExt": "css? scss?"
}
```

Or is it only possible to use one of the two?

Comment: Yes you can have both. The defaults property in `.angular-cli.json` is just to tell angular-cli which one to use whenever you create new components. Just set the value to the one you use the more often I guess

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT for Angular 6+**

[Found on GitHub page of Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10473#issuecomment-384605314):

stylePreprocessorOptions is still supported. You will have to manually update the newly generated `angular.json` though. Its new place is inside the "options" block of the json.

An example config could look like this:

```
"options": {
    "outputPath": "../webapp",
    "index": "src/index.html",
    "main": "src/main.ts",
    "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    "assets": [
        {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "src/resources",
            "output": "/resources"
        },
    ],
    "styles": [
        "src/styles.scss"
    ],
    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
            "src/styles"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": []
}
```

Note the changed path.

**ORIGINAL answer**

Actually it just went fine out-of-the-box by having the `"styleExt"` set to `"css"`. A bunch of components in a specific module were using SASS. I have a sass folder with variables and mixins and this setting in `angular-cli.json` was needed to have these scss files compiled / processed correctly:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "sass"
  ]
}
```

The application renders fine with a mix of css and scss files. I assume this `styleExt` parameter is just there for the default component style (`css, scss, less`) file generation when adding components via `angular-cli` commands.

Comment: I can't find any configuration as `stylePreprocessorOptions` or `angular-cli.json` in `angular8` application. Could you please  suggest where to make this change?

Answer (score 6):

You can have both but you have to set your style extension to SASS or CSS only.

Now of if you want to use CSS or SASS in your component just use Angular CLI to generate component like

For CSS

```
ng g component my-component --style=css
```

For SASS

```
ng g component my-component --style=sass
```

So set style extension to SASS and use CSS extensions also in your project

Comment: How is your answer different from mine? Aside from showing how to make files it's essentially the same thing

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you change the `styleExt` to scss and your css files to scss because scss is a superset of css.

Comment: That wasn't even needed...as you can read from my answer below. Thanks anyway.