# Using SCSS and CSS together

Tags: css

*Apologies if the following doesn't make sense*,
I'm very curious about one thing, using **SCSS & CSS** file together in same website. My question is can we actually use SCSS and CSS together?

Comment: SCSS will compile to regular CSS, which is what instructs the browser how to style and render the website. So yes, they can be used together :o)

Comment: This might be able to help you out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49010718/is-it-possible-to-have-both-css-and-scss-in-angular

Comment: Okay so basically, I forget to mention important thing the website project I'm working on is consist of **html**, **CSS** and **JavaScript**, so there will be no problem using **SCSS**.

Comment: Two things, yes you can have regular CSS in your SCSS files, and second you compile your SCSS files down to CSS, minified for production, not minified for development and with an accompanying map file so you can find references in the browser to the SCSS files..

Comment: [ https://github.com/new-programmer-tech/Camera-website ] check this once, I have used css and scss together.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to import CSS files directly into your sass file. The following PR in GitHub solves the issue. The syntax is the same as now - @import "your/path/to/the/file", without an extension after the file name. This will import your file directly.

Comment: Do I also need to link SCSS to html file too....I'm bit confused now?...**Thank you everyone for answering me btw**